# Serializing a list of interface objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using Json.net, I want to deserialize a basket containing interface objects.
This...

```
{
"Owner": "John",
"Fruit": [ <an apple object>, <a pear>, etc... ]
}
```

... should go into this...

```
class Basket
{
string Owner;
List<iFruit> Fruit; //contains instances of Apple, Pear,...
}
```

Interfaces cannot be instantiated, so a conversion to concrete objects is needed. I found examples using a JsonConverter to create concrete Apple and Pear instances. But the list is always created directly with a line like:

```
List<iFruit> fruit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<iFruit>>(json, new FruitConverter());
```

How do I deserialize a whole Basket, where the JsonConverter is used only for the objects in the fruit list?

Comment: I'm guessing you could use a [`JsonConverterAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) either on the `IFruit` interface or the `Fruit` member.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's as simple as that. Attribute on the interface definition. Thank you!
(if you want this marked as best answer, feel free to repeat it below.)

Comment: That's alright, I really just gave you a hint. You could post an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is simple, really.

```
[JsonConverter (typeof(IFruitConverter))]
public interface iFruit
    {

    }
```

As a sidenote, the converter is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/1311434).
I added a `CanWrite` override to the converter that returns `false`, so that it will be ignored during serialization and only come into play during deserialisation.
Thanks to @Blorgbeard!